# How to upload apk file from local path to android emulator automatically in scripting(Appium)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Currently my dev team integrated their repository with jenkins it's automatically generate apk once it build from jenkins is there anyway to install that local apk in android emulator using automation script.

Please anybody help me on this.

Comment: you means you want to run following command using java
`adb install <apk path>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using appium you can set **app** capabilities in your **DesiredCapability**.

```
 DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
 caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "path to your apk");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below mentioned Function and call it when you want to execute the .APK file on an Emulator

1. You should have Appium server running before calling this
2. this will launch the emulator for you and will install the .APK file on the same.

   ```
    protected AppiumDriver getAppiumDriver() throws MalformedURLException {

       if(appDriver == null)
       {
           DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

           // APK location on system
            File appDir = new File("/Users/therapybox/Desktop/Appium/Apps");


           /* ANDROID DEPENDENCIES START*/

           File newApp = new File (appDir ,"selendroid-test.apk" );
           cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
           cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
           cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
           cap.setCapability("platformVersion","8.0");
           cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
           cap.setCapability("avd", "Nexus5XAPI26");
           cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
           cap.setCapability("app", newApp.getAbsolutePath());
           appDriver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
       }

       return appDriver;
   }
   ```